# How to connect to SQL Server database in VS Express 2012 for Web

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ado.net

I am trying to learn to connect to and perform functions with SQL Server database using C# (out of ASP.NET website). When I try to run

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; database=fengshuidb; integrated security = SSPI");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from emails", con);
con.Open();
```

to connect I get the following error with the `con.Open()` instruction.

From VS:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server)"

What do I need to do to configure connection to database? What security settings do I need? Are there any good resources for this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Try entering the Connection this way

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Database=fengshuidb;Server=[Your_PC_Name]\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;connect timeout = 30");
```

Where "[Your_PC_Name]" is the name of you local machine if the database is local.
Also take a look at this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try using SqlConnectionStringBuilder to create a valid Connection String

Answer (score 0):

You missed Initial Catalog in your connection part.

Change it to this:

```
Data Source=Your sql connection ;Initial Catalog=Your Database name;Integrated Security=True
```